# Using exp4j and getting a strange result

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have this on my app in Eclipse and when I run it, my size comes out to be 'de.congrace.exp4j.RPNExpression@405301d0.  Can someone please educate this real green android/java pgmr wannabe?  Thanks.

Calculable result= new ExpressionBuilder("3+2").build();                size.setText(String.valueOf(result));

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using the default `Object#toString()`, which prints out the object's class and hash code. You need to call `result.calculate()`:

```
size.setText(Double.toString(result.calculate());
```

Also, don't use `String.valueOf()` on objects; it's more idiomatic and a tad faster to just call `toString()`.